# How to specify chef-client settings on bootstrap?

Tags: configuration, chef, configuration-management, knife

I'm trying to bootstrap nodes via knife. Executing:

`knife bootstrap user@server-1 -P XXX --sudo -N java-server-1`

I found a [bunch of properties](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_client.html) in client.rb on the node side that I would like to specify on bootstrap. Is it possible to do it with knife bootstrap from workstation?

---

Looks like this kind of operation is not provided. 
Also, found a helpfull cookbook: [chef-client](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/chef-client)

Comment: What properties are you specifically trying to set?